# Запуск Lua скрипта

Tags: c#, .net, lua

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NLua;
using Nlua2;

namespace Nlua2
{
  public class Test
  {
    public Test()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("IT WORKED");
    }
    static public void Method()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("IT WORKED2");
    }
  }
}

namespace Nlua
{

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Lua state = new Lua();
      Test obj = new Test();
      state["obj"] = obj; // Create a global value 'obj' of .NET type SomeClass 
                          // This could be any .NET object, from BCL or from your assemblies
      state.LoadCLRPackage();

      try
      {
        state.DoString(@"
                          import ('Nlua', 'Nlua2') 
                          local obj2 = Test()
                          obj.Method()
                        ");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }


      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

local obj2 = Test() выдает

[string "chunk"]:3: attempt to call global 'Test' (a nil value)

Comment: А что непонятного-то? Ну не знает ваш скрипт, что такое `Test`. Вы ж ему только `obj` скормили. Думаю, вам нужно убрать строчку `local obj2 = Test()` из скрипта.

Comment: а то есть import ('Nlua', 'Nlua2') не дает скрипту понять, что Test() есть? Брр, а как писать то тогда? это как бы пример из http://nlua.org/

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Попробую воспроизвести.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял - то Вы пытаетесь вызвать статический метод на инстансе объекта, что является не правильным.

Первое на что стоить обратить внимание, это на строчку импорта.

```
import ('Nlua', 'Nlua2')
```

Я бы не советовал так именовать сборки, потому что получается что что ваша сборка `Nlua` ссылается на 3th party сборку `NLua`.. так конечно делать можно, но это только дополнительная путаница.

Ну и сам вызов метода

```
obj.Method()
```

Если Вы хотите вызывать статический метод используйте для этого сам Тип, а не его инстанс.

```
Test.Method() --> only the class name!
```

> Calling static methods: You can call static methods using only the class name and the . notation from Lua.

---

Если хотите вызывать на инстансе объекта, то делаете метод не статическим

```
public void Method()
{
  Console.WriteLine("IT WORKED2");
}
```

И используйте синтаксис через `:`

```
obj2:Method()
```

или

```
obj:Method()
```

> Calling instance methods: To call instance methods you need to use the : notation, you can call methods from objects passed to Lua or to objects created inside the Lua context.

---

Если у вас присутствует сложный полиморфизм, то LuaInterface предоставляет Вам возможность руками его резолвить уже через оператор `.` (P.S.: не уверен что это ещё нужно, сейчас вроде Lua сама всё умеет резолвить, но через `.` тоже можно)

Например:

```
namespace Nlua2
{
  public class Test
  {
    public Test()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("IT WORKED");
    }

    public virtual void Method()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("IT WORKED2");
    }
  }

  public class TestDerived : Test
  {
    public override void Method()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("IT WORKED3 - Derived");
    }
  }
}

private static void Main()
{
  Lua state = new Lua();
  Test obj = new TestDerived();
  state["obj"] = obj;
  state.LoadCLRPackage();

  try
  {
    state.DoString(@"
                      import ('ConsoleApplication6', 'Nlua2') 
                      local obj2 = Test()
                      obj2.Method(obj)  --> Ссылка на this. будет напечатано IT WORKED3 - Derived
                      obj2.Method(obj2) --> Ссылка на this. будет напечанано IT WORKED2
                      obj.Method(obj)   --> Ссылка на this. будет напечатано IT WORKED3 - Derived
                      obj.Method(obj2)  --> Error.
                    ");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```